# How can I insert Product name,Unit name,Price, in my order.php

Tags: php

I'm using dynamic select box and fetch Data in database but I have big problem that I can't solve can anyone tell me or correct what mistake I write here. because every time i try to submit button only the `Product_id` save in the database here's my code i want them to be `Product_name`, `Product_quantity` `Product_unit`, `Product_price` that will store in database and not `product_id`.

delivery_form.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="deliveryformsave.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
<td align="right"><h3>Product:</h3></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
    //Include database configuration file
    include('connect-db.php');

    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_status = 'available' ORDER BY product_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    ?>

    <select name="item1" id="product" >
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php
        if($rowCount > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                echo '<option value="'.$row['product_id'].'">'.$row['product_name'].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">Product not available</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select name="quantity1" id="quantity">
        <option value="">Select Product first</option>
    </select>

    <select name="unit1" id="unit">
        <option value="">Select state first</option>
    </select>

<div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-save icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>                 

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#product').on('change',function(){
        var product_id = $(this).val();
        if(product_id){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData2.php',
                data:'product_id='+product_id,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#quantity').html(html);
                    $('#unit').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#quantity').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
            $('#unit').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });

    $('#quantity').on('change',function(){
        var product_unit = $(this).val();
        if(product_unit){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData2.php',
                data:'product_unit='+product_unit,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#city').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#unit').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here my ajaxdota2.php

```
 <?php
//Include database configuration file
include('connect-db.php');

if(isset($_POST["product_id"]) && !empty($_POST["product_id"])){
    //Get all state data

    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = ".$_POST['product_id']." AND product_status = 'available' ORDER BY product_quantity ASC");


    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">STOCK</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['product_id'].'">'.$row['product_quantity'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
    }
}


if(isset($_POST["product_unit"]) && !empty($_POST["product_unit"])){
    //Get all state data

    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = ".$_POST['product_unit']." AND product_status = 'available' ORDER BY product_unit ASC");


    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">UNIT</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['product_id'].'">'.$row['product_unit'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["product_price"]) && !empty($_POST["product_price"])){
    //Get all city data


        $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = ".$_POST['product_price']." ORDER BY product_price ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display cities list
    if($rowCount > 0){

        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['product_id'].'">'.$row['product_price'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my output in form and in database

[image]

Here is my deliveryformsave.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database");


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {



    $Date_ = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Date_']);  
    $Time_Travel = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Time_Travel']);
    $Time_IN_OUT = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Time_IN_OUT']);      
    $Driver_Name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Driver_Name']);
    $Project_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Project_name']);
    $Jobsite = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Jobsite']);
    $Foreman_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Foreman_name']);
    $supplier = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['supplier']);    
    $Vehicle = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Vehicle']);      
    $vehicle_plate_no = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['vehicle_plate_no']);    
    $item1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['item1']);
    $quantity1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['quantity1']);          
    $unit1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['unit1']);


            $sql = 
            "INSERT INTO deliveryrecords (Date_, Time_Travel, Time_IN_OUT, Driver_Name, Project_name, Jobsite, Foreman_name, supplier, Vehicle, vehicle_plate_no, item1, quantity1, unit1) "
            . "VALUES ('$Date_', '$Time_Travel', '$Time_IN_OUT', '$Driver_Name', '$Project_name', '$Jobsite', '$Foreman_name', '$supplier', '$Vehicle', '$vehicle_plate_no', '$item1', '$quantity1', '$unit1')";

             if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
                header("location: viewdelivery.php");
            }
        }   


?>
```

Comment: Are those drop-downs are cascading?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you mean, but I can't see any INSERT or UPDATE operations on the database? Post your `deliveryformsave.php`.

Comment: Your select queries are bit unclear. Because, You have selected product quantity and unit against product id. Anyway, the solution might be you have to set the respective value for those drop-downs instead of putting product_id for all. `echo '<option value="'.$row['product_unit'].'">'.$row['product_unit'].'</option>';`

Comment: you are building a dropdown for quantity: ok. You are displaying the quantities: ok. The value for each option is the product id: why?

Comment: okay sir I will post my deliveryformsave.php I cant solve this it took me 2 weeks already then I finally got here to ask question.

Comment: try displaying your query and manually running it on dbms `echo $sql;` to check if the values are really been supplied successfully or determine if there's an error in your database

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is bit unclear but if you want array of product data in your deliveryformsave.php then you can do :

```
echo '<option value="'.$row.'">'.$row['product_name'].'</option>';
```

by putting whole $row array as value of your option tag, it will send all attributes in $row to your deliveryformsave.php.
And inside that you can just insert these values by taking index of $row array as:

```
$row['Product_name'];
$row['Product_quantity'];
```

and so on...
Hope this helps.

**UPDATE: 
Looking at your deliveryformsave.php file you can use:

use $row['Product_name'] in your option with id=item1,
use $row['Product_unit'] in your option with id=quantity1
and other fields that you required to store as value.

Before that print your $row to see if array contains items as Product_name and other...

Comment: Hi sir I tried this but it doesnt the First select box is working but the second and third not working dynamically